# install RPM packages using perl

Tags: yum, rpm, perl

I'm trying to install RPM package using 'yum' through perl. But, the package is prompting to enter 'Y/N' during the install. How can i do a silent install?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yum has a `-y` option:

```
   -y, --assumeyes
          Assume yes; assume that the answer
```

See [yum(8) man page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/yum) for details.